# Generate prime factorisations of factorial numbers

Tags: python-3.x, mathematics, objective-c-runtime

The code was written to generate the factorisation of numbers into primes in ascending order. E.g 3! ='2 * 3', 4!='2^3 * 3'. When I have huge numbers such as 100!, the run time becomes a problem. I want to have a code which will run in less time.

```
from math import floor,sqrt,factorial
from decimal import Decimal
def prime(x):
   if x==2 or x==3 or x==5:
      return True
   if (x%2==0) or (x%3==0) or (x%5==0) or (x==1):
     return False
   for i in range(6,floor(sqrt(x)),6):
      if x%(i+1)==0:
         return False
      elif i%(i+5)==0:
         return False
   return True
def decomp(n):
   y=factorial(n)
   if y<7:
      pri =list(filter(prime,range(1,y+1)))
   else:
      pri=list(filter(prime,range(1,floor(Decimal(y).sqrt()+1))))
   a={};b=0
   for i in pri:
      while y%i==0:
         y=y//i
         b+=1
         a[i]=b
         b=0
   if len(list(a.keys()))==1:
      if list(a.values())!=[1]: 

         c=str(a.keys())+'^'+str(a.values())
      else:
         c=str(list(a.keys()))
   elif len(list(a.keys()))>1:
      if a[list(a.keys())[0]]>1:
         c=str(list(a.keys())[0])+'^'+str(a[list(a.keys())[0]])
  
      elif a[list(a.keys())[0]]==1:
         c=str(list(a.keys())[0])
      for key in list(a.keys())[1:]:
         if a[key]!=1:
            c+=' * '+str(key)+'^'+str(a[key])
        
         elif a[key]==1:
            c+=' * '+str(key)
        
     
   return c
```

Answer (score 6):

Given that you do `y=factorial(n)` *inside* your `decomp(n)` function, I'm gonna assume that this is really about factoring factorials. And my review is gonna be:

- **Don't compute the factorial at all.**
- Use a better function name.
- Document what the function does.
- Separate the factorization from the presentation. Return something more useful than a string, like pairs of primes and their exponents. That can then be pretty-formatted if desired, or used for computations.
- **Test your code**, because for example for `decomp(10)` returns `'2 * 3 * 5 * 7'`, missing the exponents.

Instead of computing the factorial and then factoring that, factor all the numbers from 1 to n and combine their prime factorizations. Or even better... compute, for every prime from 1 to n, its exponent in n!. Let's say we want to find the exponent for 3 in 100!. Every third number from 1 to 100 (i.e., 3, 6, 9, 12, etc) contributes a factor 3, so there are \$\lfloor\frac{100}{3}\rfloor=33\$ numbers that contribute factor 3. Of those, every third number (i.e., 9, 18, 27, etc) contributes *another* factor 3. Of those, every third number (i.e., 27, 54 and 81) contributes *yet another*. And 81 even contributes a fourth. So the exponent for 3 in 100! is 33+11+3+1=48.

Here's an O(n) solution doing that. Takes my laptop about 0.33 seconds to factor 1,000,000!. Compare that to just computing `math.factorial(10**6)`, which already takes about 10 seconds.

```python
def factorial_factorization(n):
    """Return the prime factorization of n! as list of (prime, exponent) pairs."""
    
    # Compute primes from 2 to n, see https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/prime-sieve-linear.html
    lp = [None] * (n+1)
    primes = []
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        if not lp[i]:
            primes.append(i)
            lp[i] = i
        for p in primes:
            if p > lp[i] or i * p > n:
                break
            lp[i * p] = p

    # Find prime exponents for n!
    result = []
    for p in primes:
        e = 0
        m = n // p
        while m:
            e += m
            m //= p
        result.append((p, e))
    return result
```

Demo:

```
>>> factorial_factorization(3)
[(2, 1), (3, 1)]

>>> factorial_factorization(4)
[(2, 3), (3, 1)]

>>> factorial_factorization(100)
[(2, 97), (3, 48), (5, 24), (7, 16), (11, 9), (13, 7), (17, 5), (19, 5), (23, 4), (29, 3), (31, 3), (37, 2), (41, 2), (43, 2), (47, 2), (53, 1), (59, 1), (61, 1), (67, 1), (71, 1), (73, 1), (79, 1), (83, 1), (89, 1), (97, 1)]

>>> factorial_factorization(10**6)[:10]
[(2, 999993), (3, 499993), (5, 249998), (7, 166664), (11, 99998), (13, 83332), (17, 62497), (19, 55553), (23, 45453), (29, 35713)]
```

If you want a less useful but prettier presentation, that's easy to do then:

```
>>> n = 42
>>> print(f'{n}! =', ' * '.join(f'{p}^{e}' if e > 1 else f'{p}'
                                for p, e in factorial_factorization(n)))
42! = 2^39 * 3^19 * 5^9 * 7^6 * 11^3 * 13^3 * 17^2 * 19^2 * 23 * 29 * 31 * 37 * 41
```

Checking that:

```
>>> s = '2^39 * 3^19 * 5^9 * 7^6 * 11^3 * 13^3 * 17^2 * 19^2 * 23 * 29 * 31 * 37 * 41'
>>> (result := eval(s.replace('^', '**')))
1405006117752879898543142606244511569936384000000000

>>> (expect := math.factorial(42))
1405006117752879898543142606244511569936384000000000

>>> result == expect
True
```

Answer (score 3):

Your prime decomposition could be much (much) more efficient.

Let's look at what you're doing right now : You create a big number (let's say \$100!\$), then get all the primes between between 1 and \$\sqrt (100!)\$ to then check if they are a factor of your number.

One efficient but not "fun" approach would be to cache a predefined table of prime numbers up to a certain high value and use this cache to determine prime factorization.

At the moment, you effectively check if a number is a prime twice, which is costly. Why not simply do this :

```
def prime_factorization(n):

    primes = []
    for i in range(2,int(sqrt(n))):
        if n == 1:
            return primes

        while n % i == 0:
            n = n // i
            primes.append(i)
```

Is it efficient? Not so much, but we only look at every number once. And since we start from

How could it be more efficient? Our big problem is the `range(2,sqrt(n))`. We'd like to be a little bit more specific as to which number we look at. You could create a prime number generator (using the `yield` keyword) that would return only primes. There are a billion ways to create efficient prime number generators, so I'll skip on this. But then :

```
def prime_factorization(n):

    primes = []
    for i in prime_generator(from=2, to=sqrt(n)):
        if n == 1:
            return primes

        while n % i == 0:
            n = n / i
            primes.append(i)
```

Then you'd have something pretty fast and simple.

Lastly, I would recommend wrapping all your code to print your result in another function, as it would make `decomp` clearer.

Comment: @superbrain replace `/`with `//`

Comment: @superbrain You're right, `range` must be complaining for being passed a non-integer upper bound.

Comment: @!EatBagels It seems OP only wants factorials to be factorized. In this case, the upper limit of `sqrt(n!)` is overkill. No prime factor will exceed `n`.

Comment: @ChristophFrings Yeah, even computing n! at all is overkill then (though easy and cheap in Python).

Comment: @superbrain You're right, I wrote this answer fast-ish and didn't test out my code.

Comment: @ChristophFrings Excellent point, although in this case I'm "lucky" because since the range is never evaluated as a list, the function will terminate before the range goes higher than `n`.

Comment: Now `prime_factorization(6)` returns `None`. And there's still `/` in the second solution. With numbers like 100! it matters, as you'd get rounding errors, which leads to wrong results and introduces factors much larger than n (so it'll be slow after all).